# Java: aggregate failed. CouldNotLoadRequirementsException

Tags: java, pom.xml, serenity-bdd

I am receiving the following error within my java project and could not find much help online on knowing where to start in trying to fix this problem. Can anybody give me some insight on possible things I can do to try and sort out this error please:

> Failed to execute goal
>   net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.4.1-rc.6:aggregate
>   (serenity-reports) on project StudentApp: Execution serenity-reports
>   of goal
>   net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:1.4.1-rc.6:aggregate
>   failed. CouldNotLoadRequirementsException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try using a more recent version of Serenity (1.9.7 is the latest).

Comment: The problem with using latest version is it causes issues within a variety different places in the pom file. Are we ok to go into chat and I explain what is happening? It's basically when I include the following within serenity.properties: serenity.test.root=com.studentapp.junit then the error appears. I remove this and I get the report but I want to use the serenty test root to group tests together within the report

Comment: Of I can send you the project and the service I'm testing against if easier?

Comment: You was right, latest version of serenity followed by adding a lot of dependencies in related to jetty has fixed the issue